# Wagtail AssertionError "Unmatched tags: expected img, got p"

Tags: postgresql, docker, editor, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm running Wagtail 2.4 in Docker with a Postgres db, and getting an error when I attempt to edit a blog post in Wagtail. The initial post worked, and I can view the page fine on the site. When I go to edit the post in the Wagtail admin, it throws a 500 error: `AssertionError "Unmatched tags: expected img, got p"`

I initially thought that the issue was because the blog posts were initially imported from another database (old Drupal site) and the `intro` and `body` fields contained image tags, even though the intro should not have had any HTML markup at all. However, I removed them in the db using Navicat and the error is still occurring. Not sure what else to try, but I can confirm that not all posts are getting an error on the edit view, just the ones that were imported from Drupal. Anything newer that has been added in the Wagtail admin is fine.

The model looks like this:

```
class NewsPage(Page):    
    main_image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORIES)
    intro = models.TextField()
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    search_keywords = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
        FieldPanel('category'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname='full'),
    ]

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
        FieldPanel('search_keywords'),
    ]

    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
    ]

    @property
    def news_index_page(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewsPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['news_index_page'] = self.news_index_page
        context['news'] = self
        return context
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py" in wrapper
  102.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py" in decorated_view
  34.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py" in edit
  545.         'has_unsaved_changes': has_unsaved_changes,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  858.                             current = current()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render_form_content
  252.         return mark_safe(self.render_as_object() + self.render_missing_fields())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render_as_object
  220.         return self.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render
  324.             'self': self

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  858.                             current = current()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render_as_object
  220.         return self.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render
  324.             'self': self

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  858.                             current = current()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in render_as_object
  482.             'field': self.bound_field,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  188.             return template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  173.                 return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  53.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  698.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templatetags/wagtailadmin_tags.py" in render_with_errors
  251.         return bound_field.as_widget()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  93.             renderer=self.form.renderer,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  241.         context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/rich_text/editors/draftail/__init__.py" in get_context
  62.         context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in get_context
  293.         context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in get_context
  233.             'value': self.format_value(value),

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/rich_text/editors/draftail/__init__.py" in format_value
  59.         return self.converter.from_database_format(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/rich_text/converters/contentstate.py" in from_database_format
  84.         self.html_to_contentstate_handler.feed(html)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/html/parser.py" in feed
  111.         self.goahead(0)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/html/parser.py" in goahead
  173.                     k = self.parse_endtag(i)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/html/parser.py" in parse_endtag
  421.         self.handle_endtag(elem.lower())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/rich_text/converters/html_to_contentstate.py" in handle_endtag
  313.         assert name == expected_name, "Unmatched tags: expected %s, got %s" % (expected_name, name)

Exception Type: AssertionError at /admin/pages/2251/edit/
Exception Value: Unmatched tags: expected img, got p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Wagtail's parser is not tolerant of badly formed HTML, and the HTML you've imported from Drupal is badly formed (e.g., it includes unclosed tags). It's a little annoying that the Wagtail editor breaks with this because you have no way to fix the content from the editor.

What I've ended up doing in the past is fixing the bad HTML in the shell, using an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in NewsPage.objects.all():
    html = page.body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
    cleaned_html = soup.body.decode_contents()
    page.body = cleaned_html
    page.save()
```

`decode_contents()` will generate valid HTML that Wagtail's parser will not complain about.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking into using BeautifulSoup to remove the img tags altogether and it's working nicely, as I can see they are removed in the database. However, I'm still getting the error in the edit view within Wagtail, and I'm wondering if it's just not recognizing the change in the database for some reason?

Comment: It's not enough to remove `img` tags - you need to clean all badly formed HTML - things like unclosed `p` tags etc, which if you're coming from Drupal you're likely to have a lot of.

Comment: The issue was that not only the pages themselves had to be cleaned, but also the json in the `wagtailcore_pagerevision` table. That is what the edit view is loading.

Answer (score 0):

My solution that ended up working was as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in NewsPage.objects.all():
    html = page.body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    if soup.find("img"):
        soup.img.decompose()

    page.body = soup
    page.save_revision().publish()
```